# Using cmake to cross-compile a project that uses ProtoBuf

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to add protocol buffers in to a cmake build where were cross-compile to ARM. This is a custom board and it is impossible to build on the target, I must be able to cross-compile.

The issue I'm having is that to take the .proto file and generate the x.pb.c file, I need to use the host computer version of protoc and it's libraries, but when I use the generated x.pb.c in source files I need to use the ARM version of libraries to build my application.  If I don't I get the following error at link time:

```
/usr/bin/ld.lld-5.0: error: /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so is incompatible with armelf_linux_eabi
```

The error is correct, because the file at:

```
/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so
```

is the host version and not the ARM version.  The arm version is at:

```
/mnt/c/zprotocol/linux_arm/lib/libprotobuf.so
```

The cmake file for when I generate the x.pb.c file is:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.5 )
project( base )

set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11 )

include( FindProtobuf )
find_package( Protobuf REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR} )

protobuf_generate_cpp( PROTO_SRC PROTO_HEADER test.proto )

add_library( proto ${PROTO_HEADER} ${PROTO_SRC} )
target_link_libraries( proto ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES} )
```

This all works great and I get my generated file no problem.  I can't figure out how to tell cmake that when linking the application that uses the generated protocol buffer files that it needs to be looking in a different path.

I think the find_package is somehow setting paths for the entire build.  I've tried adding the appropriate path in the cmake files for applications using the generate protocol files via:

```
include_directories( /mnt/c/zprotocol/linux_arm/lib/ )
```

and

```
set( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -L /mnt/c/zprotocol/linux_arm/lib" )
```

to no success.

Anybody have a suggestions I could try?  I'm still learning cmake so maybe there is something obvious that I haven't figure out yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Brian, did you ever figure out how to do this? Care to post an answer?

Comment: @MarkR sadly, that's the question I was going to ask! :-(